# Stage 'UTIL_DB.PUBLIC.LIKE_A_WINDOW_INTO_AN_S3_BUCKET' does not exist or not authorized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

*UPDATE:* solved by transferring ownership of stage to Sysadmin via Data-->databases->Util/public--> Click on the stage right upper corner-->Transfer ownership to Sysadmin.

Also the syntax for the COPY INTO commands should be like:

```
copy into LU_SOIL_TYPE
from @util_db.public.like_a_window_into_an_s3_bucket
files = ('LU_SOIL_TYPE.tsv')
file_format = (format_name='L8_CHALLENGE_FF');
```

I am doing a challenge in Snowflake under lesson 8 for Badge 1.

We created an stage and I checked the information about the stage object created, see image.
And the error I get is that the stage does not exist or not autorized, how could that be if is created under util/public ownership by sysadmin? please see screenshots of:
-Stage

- Error[image: stage_ingo][image: copy_into_error_snowflake]

Comment: Are you sure stage was created by role `SYSADMIN`? I believe you created the stage as `ACCOUNTADMIN`.

Comment: Hi Sergiu, I just transferred ownership of the stage to Sysadmin, that was the main issue.

Comment: I have more questions Sergiu, if you dont mind?